# Vb.net InputLanguage of the windows

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i tried to get the current keboard language of the **windows**

the language bar:

[image]

My code:

```
Private Sub Form1_InputLanguageChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguageChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.InputLanguageChanged

    Me.Text = e.InputLanguage.LayoutName

End Sub
```

This code can get the **Form** language only

I want to get the current **windows** language from the **language bar.**

Do I need to use user32.dll?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Changed code to call a PInvoke [GetKeyboardLayoutName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929435.aspx)(...). Unfortunatelly this is only a number - still working on retrieving the correct name.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    If GetKeyboardLayoutName(sb) Then
        Me.Text = sb.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Private Shared Function GetKeyboardLayoutName(pwszKLID As StringBuilder) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: when i put your code in timer event and then i pressing "Alt+Shift" the Console Write the same language(my default windows language) and not the current language from the language bar.

Comment: this code return : 0000040D when i change the language it still "0000040D". but if i change the language when my form is in focus the it changed to 00000409 , if i open new text file and then i changing the language Nothing happens. this code works only for the form.

Comment: I am getting 00000809 for english and 00000407 for german when I change my keyboard settings

Comment: if the focus on another application and the you change the language  Nothing happens , your code can get the current language of your form only (System.Windows.Forms). try to change language when notepad is on focus. if you try it you will understand me. :)

Comment: each window has his own keyboard language, so i don't understand what you want? there is no "current **windows** language from the _language bar_." but there are culture settings which belong to the system! compare original answer (eg: [CulturInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx))